# Laravel Route redirecting to the right controller when using parameters [architecture]

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So building a few pages on the same template and loading the content via AJAX. Most of the content are forms. Views are defined by step number (1,2,3,4,5....32)

Here is how I built my route:

```
Route::get('onboarding/', [
    'as' => 'get-onboarding-start',
    'uses' => 'OnboardingController@getStart'
]);
Route::get('onboarding/{i}', [
    'as' => 'get-onboarding-step',
    'uses' => 'OnboardingController@getNextStep'
]);
Route::post('onboarding/{i}', [
    'as' => 'post-onboarding-step',
    'uses' => 'OnboardingController@postStepForm'
]);
```

Now one method in the controller cannot handle all the work. Meaning I will need to redirect to another method based on the $i (step number).

I am afraid that it is not simple to read if I put a big blog of switch case $i = 1,2,3...
At the same time I don't want to write 32 different routes.

What would you propose?

1. Hard code all the routes meaning: 'onboarding/username' then
   'onboarding/email' etc... etc... The good point is that it is super
   simple to read in the views and you know exactly what the next step
   is... no need to check what the number corresponds to.
2. Catch all as coded now and redirect to different methods in the controller
3. Something better, super easy to read and with little lines of
   code... which is .... ??

Comment: So redirect logic action in your method to another methods if you don't do this in router.

Answer (score 1):

If these steps are going to remain as they are without many changes in the future, I'd go for the first option (having 32 get & 32 post routes). This will keep your application simple, if you'd want to apply parameters or middleware to them you can use `route groups`. Below I've posted a small code example from the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. After discussion I think I will also just load the steps at once in the DOM and then store the datas in Session and send them back grouped... Agreed on the verbose being descriptive to keep it simple